# Do mapping cones involving Hausdorff spaces preserve the Hausdorff property?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $p(x)$ be the usual mapping that takes $S^n$ to $RP^n$.  I would like to show that the associated mapping cone of $S^n$, where $(1,x) \in$ {1} x $S^n$ is identified with $p(x)$, is Hausdorff.  I have shown that this mapping cone is equivalent to $D^{n+1} \sqcup RP^n$/($(1,x)$ ~ $p(x)$).  Since $D^{n+1}$ is Hausdorff, I think that the set of equivalence classes corresponding to $int$ $D^{n+1}$ will be Hausdorff.  How do I show that the set of equivalence classes belonging to the $\partial D^{n+1} \cong${1} x $S^n$, hence those identified to $p(x)$, are also Hausdorff?

Comment: It's not the points that are Hausdorff it is the space. To your question: take two points that are not equal (different equivalence classes) and produce disjoint neighborhoods around them. This isn't that different from the general problem of proving that a CW complex is Hausdorff. Actually, i found it easier to prove that CW complexes are normal (by producing separating functions to $[0,1]$). .

Comment: Based on your comments, I have looked at Hatcher for reference since I was just introduced to CW complexes last spring and have not yet had the opportunity to consider whether they have this property.  So, in general, CW complexes are normal, hence Hausdorff.  In particular, the mapping cone defined by $S^n$, $RP^n$, and $p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is the quotient map taking $S^n$ to $RP^n$, is equivalent to the CW complex defined by $D^{n+1}$ attached to $RP^n$ with $p(x)$ as the attaching map.  Therefore, this mapping cone is Hausdorff?

Comment: I have also edited my original post according to your comments.